# Require PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, require

I am writing a code in PHP which is not fully completed. When I open this `register.php` script in my browser there is only a blank page, because I can't get over `require('config.php')`. When I delete `require('config.php')` everything will appear in my browser.

Could you please help me and tell what is wrong with my `require`?

```
<?php

require('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
} else {
    $form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <Br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /> <Br/>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /> <Br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /> <Br/>
Email2: <input type="text" name="email2" /> <Br/>
Pass: <input type="password" name="pass1" /> <Br/>
Pass2: <input type="password" name="pass2" /> <Br/>
<input type="submit" value="register" name="submit" />      
</form>
EOT;
    echo $form;
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of you file(s) and tell us if you get any: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: post `config.php` also ..

Comment: It gives a fatal error because the path is incorrect. If you turned on error reporting you would've seen the error.

Comment: Your current working dir is probably not what you think it is. Use a relative path to the current dir using `__DIR__ . '/config.php'` or change the current working dir using `chdir`. Also enable error reporting because it will tell what in specific is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `require` function will look for the file `config.php`. If this is not found, it will give you an error. This error might be only visible if you put the following lines in your document:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Taken from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php):

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
>   halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue.
>
> See the include documentation for how this works.

---

If you want PHP to not give you an error when the file is not found, you could replace `require` with `include`. This means when it doesn't find the file, it still runs the code afterwards.

For solving the actual issue, you could check if `config.php` is in the right place. If this isn't the case, create a file called `config.php` in the same folder where your `register.php` is.

If your `config.php` is in the right place, check if that file doesn't has any errors, if it does, the `require` function isn't going to function aswell.

Comment: @PeeHaa You're right, thank you, it does only give you an warning like `include`.

Comment: And where is the answer? What is if OP also has errors in his `config.php` file?

Comment: @Rizier123 The last 2 paragraphs? And thank you, adding that to my answer.

Comment: This is just guess work! You don't know this. It could also be that he has an error in his config file!

Comment: @Rizier123 You're right, the next time i'm going to ask if he can post he's `config` file :)

Answer (score 0):

**Description**:-Its happens because if you use require('config.php'); that's mean its necessary to have the file "config.php",if php is not able to find the file than its going to give you an fatal error but as you told it doesn't display anything that's mean in your **php.ini** file either display_error is off or error_reporting is not set.

so you need to set error_reporting = E_ALL or 
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT and display_errors = On in php.ini file or either you can use command in your php code to turn it on                             **ini_set("display_errors", 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);.**

**Require**:-require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script.
**include** :-include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue.

Comment: You should add some white-space and look at the code formatting tools here on SO.